# PHPExcel set border and format for all sheets in spreadsheet

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'm currently trying to set all borders for my spreadsheet, also formatting such as autosize.

My code below is working, for sheet 1. All other sheets inside the spreadsheet are completely untouched. I've been trying to get it to work with all other sheets inside this spreadsheet but with no luck.

Any ideas on how i can global set the formatting so that all sheets have borders and autosize? The layout of all sheets in this spreadsheet are all the same. I'm exporting to XLSX file.

Cheers,

```
/**autosize*/
for ($col = 'A'; $col != 'P'; $col++) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);
}


/** Borders for all data */
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle(
    'A2:' . 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn() . 
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow()
)->getBorders()->getAllBorders()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);



/** Borders for heading */
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle(
    'A1:O1'
)->getBorders()->getAllBorders()->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THICK);
```

EXTRA QUESTION:
I've currently set headings. The headings do appear on sheet 1, but do not appear in any other sheets.. is it possible to show the headings in all sheets?
The headings are set in Row 1. and the results are from Row 2 down.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Asset_id');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('B1', 'Asset_name');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C1', 'Asset_type');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('D1', 'Asset_make');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('E1', 'Asset_model');
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can set a default style for the entire workbook (all worksheets):

```
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
    ->getBorders()
    ->getTop()
        ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
    ->getBorders()
    ->getBottom()
        ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
    ->getBorders()
    ->getLeft()
        ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
    ->getBorders()
    ->getRight()
        ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
```

or

```
  $styleArray = array(
      'borders' => array(
          'allborders' => array(
              'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN
          )
      )
  );
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

And this can be used for all style properties, not just borders.

But column autosizing is `structural` rather than `stylistic`, and has to be set for each column on each worksheet individually.

EDIT

Note that default workbook style only applies to Excel5 Writer

Comment: I got an error for option 1: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Can only get pseudo-border for supervisor.' in C:\wamp\www\site\Excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Style\Borders.php on line 384
( ! ) Exception: Can only get pseudo-border for supervisor. in C:\wamp\www\site\Excel\Classes\PHPExcel\Style\Borders.php on line 384

Comment: My bad, you have to set individual borders, or use the applyFromArray() method to set allborders

Comment: I've decided to use Excel5 and its now working: option 1, HOWEVER is there any way I can limit the amount of borders drawn like from my code above, from A2?

Comment: There isn't any way you can limit it if you set a default; because by its nature a default applies to everything unless you specify otherwise... a workbook default automatically applies to all cells in all worksheets. But you can over-ride the default for individual cells or cell ranges

Comment: One more question, I've posted another edit in the original question. Thanks

Comment: There is no automatic way of setting headings in all sheets automatically; though you could copy content and style from one sheet to the next as you create each new sheet, or clone the sheet with only the headings and add the clone to the workbook rather than creating a new sheet

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($s=65; $s<=90; $s++) {
    //echo chr($s);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension(chr($s))->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Comment: ascii capital letter offsets.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your `extra question`:

You can set which rows should be repeated on every page using:

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getPageSetup()->setRowsToRepeatAtTopByStartAndEnd(1, 5);`

Now, row 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 will be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

*In 2022 (phpoffice/phpspreadsheet  v1.22.0*), based on latest changes, the solution for applying a style to entire worksheet is:

```
$worksheet->getParent()->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray([
    'font' => [
        'name' => $pValue->getFont()->getName(),
        'size' => $pValue->getFont()->getSize(),
    ],
]);
```

for more info, refer to this [link](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/migration-from-PHPExcel/#worksheetgetdefaultstyle)

based on documentation, now we have:

**Worksheet::setDefaultStyle()**

```
// Before
$worksheet->setDefaultStyle($value);

// After
$worksheet->getParent()->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray([
    'font' => [
        'name' => $pValue->getFont()->getName(),
        'size' => $pValue->getFont()->getSize(),
    ],
]);
```