# is it possible to put bottom border of a merged cell in phpexcel?

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel

```
 $objectSheet->setCellValue($c[$current_col].$current_row, 'Civil Status:');

 $objectSheet->mergeCells($c[$current_col].$current_row.':'.$c[$current_col + $width -1].$current_row);

 $current_col += $width;
```

I want to put bottom border in the merged cell, how can i do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPEXCEL set border and format for all sheets in spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397953/phpexcel-set-border-and-format-for-all-sheets-in-spreadsheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397953/phpexcel-set-border-and-format-for-all-sheets-in-spreadsheet)

```
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
->getBorders()
->getTop()
    ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);

$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
->getBorders()
->getBottom()
    ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);

$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
->getBorders()
->getLeft()
    ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);

$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()
->getBorders()
->getRight()
    ->setBorderStyle(PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN);
```

Comment: $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('B'.$cellnumber)-> applyFromArray($style);