# How to simplify add excel cell border using PHP script without Plugins

Tags: php

I have the code below to put string and number into excel using PHP Script.

```
protected function _write_number($row, $col, $value)
{
    echo pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $row, $col, 0x0);
    echo pack("d", $value);
    return;
}
protected function _write_string($row, $col, $value)
{
    $len    = strlen($value);
    echo pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $len, $row, $col, 0x0, $len);
    echo $value;
    return;
}
```

Now, i want to make border of cell. Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHPEXCEL set border and format for all sheets in spreadsheet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19397953/phpexcel-set-border-and-format-for-all-sheets-in-spreadsheet)

Comment: Thanks man. But i don't use any plugins. I just wondering how to add border in cell. Is that possible to use pack() too or something else?